# Symfony2 - No default option is configured for constraint

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I was following tutorial book for Symfony2.
I was doing project with forms.

Chapter 12: Forms | 150

My code:

```
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
   $task = new Task();
   $task->setTask('Find EiM group');
   $task->setDueDate(new DateTime('tomorrow'));

   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
      ->add('task', 'text')
      ->add('dueDate', 'date')
      ->add('save', 'submit')
      ->getForm();

   return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

And I'm getting error from the topic.

```
No default option is configured for constraint Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime
```

What it can be?
How to fix it?
I followed example in book strictly.

Answer (score 29):

This:

```
$task->setDueDate(new DateTime('tomorrow'));
```

should be:

```
$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
```

Notice the forward slash before Datetime. Check your "use" statement, you probably imported and are using the class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime"

Answer (score 1):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

I'm not sure, but after this doc, the basic usage is :

```
$builder->add('publishedAt', 'date', array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'choice',
));
```

or

```
$builder->add('publishedAt', 'date', array(
    'input'  => 'timestamp',
    'widget' => 'choice',
));
```

Maybe should you try to insert the option array after the

> 'date'

Comment: Jahnux73: am I missing something? your first and second example are identical.

Comment: When reading the docs, i've seen that you have to insert the options array after the 'date' in the builder.... I update the second exemple, it's from the doc...  (array('input=>..........)